# how to align fabric objects with rotation?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I my fabric application, I want to align the selected objects, for example, to the left. Because objects might be rotated (and or scaled), thus, aligning objects actually mean align the bounding boxes of the objects to some edge.

For non-rotated objects, that's quite trivial to implement. 
See sample code below:

```
// find the minimum 'left' value
// function 'min' is used to find the minimum value of a 
// given array of objects by comparing the property value 
// which is returned by a given callback function
const { minValue } = min(objects, object => {
  const left = object.get('left');
  const originX = object.get('originX');
  if (originX === 'center') {
    return left - (object.get('width') * object.get('scaleX')) / 2;
  }
  return left;
});
objects.forEach(object => {
  if (object.get('originX') === 'center') {
    object.set('left', minValue + (
      object.get('width') * object.get('scaleX')
    ) / 2);
  } else {
    object.set('left', minValue);
  }
});
canvas.renderAll();
```

However, it's quite complicated for rotated objects. I have to translate the rotated objects either horizontally or vertically to some calculated offset/distance.

Can anybody give some advise on this? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After a small research, I found this [demo](http://fabricjs.com/bounding-rectangle) on the official fabricjs website.

Basically you can do:

```
var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();
```

Then use `bound.top`, `bound.left`, `bound.width`, `bound.height` as the bounding rectangle coordinates.